# Is actionlib/msg directory deprecated in Fuerte?

Tags: ros, action, ros-fuerte, actionlib, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the fuerte distribution, `/opt/ros/furte/share/actionlib` directory contains `action` directly but does not have `msg` directory.

Does this mean that we have to create msg files from Test.action, TestRequest.action and TwoInts.action when we'd like to use these msg files directly?
Since I'm developing my own ROS client libraries and need to read msg files under actionlib. Other packages contains action directory ( for example move_base_msgs ) also have msg directory and this wouldn't be a problem for me.

Fuerte:

```
$ ls action/
Test.action  TestRequest.action  TwoInts.action
```

Electric:

```
$ ls action/ msg
action/:
Test.action  TestRequest.action  TwoInts.action

msg:
TestAction.msg                 TestRequestGoal.msg
TestActionFeedback.msg         TestRequestResult.msg
TestActionGoal.msg             TestResult.msg
TestActionResult.msg           TwoIntsAction.msg
TestFeedback.msg               TwoIntsActionFeedback.msg
TestGoal.msg                   TwoIntsActionGoal.msg
TestRequestAction.msg          TwoIntsActionResult.msg
TestRequestActionFeedback.msg  TwoIntsFeedback.msg
TestRequestActionGoal.msg      TwoIntsGoal.msg
TestRequestActionResult.msg    TwoIntsResult.msg
TestRequestFeedback.msg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31818/is-actionlib/msg-directory-deprecated-in-fuerte?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2012-04-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Handling of messages has changed in Fuerte. Message headers for C++ are installed in /opt/ros/fuerte/include/, python files are installed in /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages//msg and lisp files in /opt/ros/fuerte/share/common-lisp/ros/.

Generation of message files for actions are just a temporary step and the msg files themselves are normally not required for compiling ros packages. As far as I can see, they are installed at the moment into /opt/ros/fuerte/share/actionlib/tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-actionlib-1.8.4-0oneiric-20120406-2119/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/actions_gen/. Not sure if that's actually a bug in the debian tool chain.

If you need the msg files, I guess you can use the script genaction.py that comes with actionlib_msgs. E.g.:

```
rosrun actionlib_msgs genaction.py /path/to/action/Foo.action -o /path/for/generated/files
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-04-16**:
Thanks for the answer.  This seems "double standard" for me, since some package contains both "action" and "msg" as move_base_msgs, and some only have "action" as actionlib. Is there REP for defining this?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-16**:
Everything now needs to be flagged to be installed.  It sounds like these should be flagged for installation by the macros.  I suggest you open a ticket at https://github.com/willowgarage/catkin/issues

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-05-09**:
add the link to the ticket https://github.com/willowgarage/catkin/issues/122